# how to do visual regression testing between two envrionment which is hosted in cloud

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I heard that there is a option in playwright we can do visual regression testing by screenshot, I am just checking Is there any possibility to do the visual regression testing by comparing two website which are hosted in cloud.

Basically I want to run the regression test between two envrionment UAT and Production which need to compare Page layout, text drop down option, checkbox, textbox, position,tooltip againts the other environment.

my page structure is similar to https://playwright.dev/docs/running-tests will have left navigation with list of different section and right side, it will open up the respective content and responsive question.

Is it possible to compare two different envrionment page layout and all other stuff using playwright on the cloud?

suggest if you have any other option